# How to calculate the breakeven rate for a UK index-linked bond?

Tags: bond-yields

I have yields for UK index-linked bonds with particular maturity dates.

e.g  "Maturity": "26/01/2035" and "Yield": "-0,129875"
I want to calculate the breakeven rate for that particular bond.

The data I have for government bond yields is for benchmark gilts.
e.g "Tenor": 15Y and "Yield": 3.081%

To calculate the breakeven rate, would I look for the closest benchmark bond and calculate the difference between the two yields?